# MySQL: Getting list of groups with their total member count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `groups` and `group_members`

`groups` has one of the columns `srno` which is integer and is the primary key

`group_members` has column `group_srno` which is foreign key mapped to `srno` of table `groups`

`group_members` has another column `member_profile_srno` which is integer

**Sample data:**

`groups` has rows:

```
srno    groupname
1       firstgroup
2       secondgroup
3       thirdgroup
4       fourthgroup
```

`group_members` has rows:

```
group_srno  member_profile_srno
1               147258
1               132678
1               551766
2               347799
2               556657
3               147258
3               365376
3               576252
3               682762
4               147258
4               465545
```

I wish to list all rows from `groups` which has given `member_profile_srno` is a member. In the same query I also wish to get total number of members each of the listed group is having.

So my code is running this query (for instance where value of `member_profile_srno` is 147258):

```
select distinct grps.*,
       count(grpmembrs1.member_profile_srno) as grpmembrscount 
from groups as grps 
  inner join group_members as grpmembrs1 on grpmembrs1.group_srno = grps.srno
  inner join group_members as grpmembrs2 on grpmembrs2.group_srno = grps.srno  
where grpmembrs1.member_profile_srno = 147258 
group by grps.srno;
```

This returns me expected results.

```
srno    groupname       grpmembrscount
1       firstgroup      3
3       thirdgroup      4
4       fourthgroup     2
```

I mean I get all the groups who is having 147258 as a member and also it lists total members count for each of those groups.

However, I am not sure why the join `grpmembrs2` exists in the query when it is not referred anywhere. However, if I remove that join, `grpmembrscount` doesn't get correct values (it is `1` for all rows).

Any idea why is this happening and is this correct way to do it?

Comment: update your question add   a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: The use of `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` as you have it looks suspicious and possibly unnecessary.  Please show us some data.

Comment: Ok I will update the question with some data in some time. Thanks!

Comment: This query doesn't follow the SQL Ansi definition which is all columns in select list must be in group by section. Only MySql allows this uggly thing which probably is causing your problem. That join `grpmembrs2` serves for nothing and if you take it out and it bring you wrong results, your query is wrong from the start.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think that unnecessary second join and the select distinct are somehow cancelling each other out.  Just my hunch.

Comment: I just quickly tried by removing distinct but behavior is same

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't believe that is the case here, a second join with the same table cause nothing to the query itself it is like it doesn't exist at all (that second join).

Comment: @JorgeCampos `select u.*, count(*) as num_posts from users u join posts using(user_id)` will not work without the join with `posts`, even though nothing is selected from it.

Comment: Question updated with sample data

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I'm not sure if I understood your comment Paul. Your sample query will not work at all regarding sql ansi, without a group by clause. Regarding the join in your sample it will not work IF the join doesn't match any row for the tables,  `select u.*, count(*) as num_posts from users` work just fine as long as there are rows in users table (Mysql specific here)

Comment: @JorgeCampos You're right - I forgot `group by u.user_id`. The point is that you can't count the posts without joining the `posts` table. The same is for OPs second join. Without that join you can't count the members of the groups. Note that `grpmembrs1` is limited to only one person (`grpmembrs1.member_profile_srno = 147258`).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel hmmm now I understand. Thanks for clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except of the unnecessary `DISTICT` this query is perfectly fine. And with MySQLs [Detection of Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) it should even work with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

You need the second join to produce the correct number of rows which you want to count according to the number of members in each group. There is no need to refer any column of `grpmembrs2` in the SELECT clause. But if you want, you can use `COUNT(grpmembrs2.group_srno)`. It doesn't matter which column you use for `COUNT()` as long as it doesn't contain any NULLs. You can also just use `COUNT(*)` and let the optimizer decide, which column to use.